# Problem with systemd starting watchdog

Tags: systemd, watchdog

I am trying to enable the `watchdog` service (on Raspbian Jessie).

I have installed `watchdog` and (hopefully) configured it.
`sudo systemctl start watchdog` seems to start it OK

`systemctl status watchdog.service` shows it running:-

```
● watchdog.service - watchdog daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service; static)
   Active: active (running) since Mon 2017-02-20 15:52:46 AEDT; 22s ago
  Process: 1828 ExecStart=/bin/sh -c [ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 1824 ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c [ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 1831 (watchdog)
   CGroup: /system.slice/watchdog.service
           └─1831 /usr/sbin/watchdog
```

When I try to enable it with `sudo systemctl enable watchdog` I get this strange output

```
Synchronizing state for watchdog.service with sysvinit using update-rc.d...
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d watchdog defaults
Executing /usr/sbin/update-rc.d watchdog enable
The unit files have no [Install] section. They are not meant to be enabled
using systemctl.
Possible reasons for having this kind of units are:
1) A unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's
   .wants/ or .requires/ directory.
2) A unit's purpose may be to act as a helper for some other unit which has
   a requirement dependency on it.
3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path, timer,
   D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...).
```

Trying `sudo update-rc.d watchdog enable` did not seem to be successful either
systemctl list-units | grep watchdog

`cat /lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service` indeed has no [Install] section

```
[Unit]
Description=watchdog daemon
Conflicts=wd_keepalive.service
After=multi-user.target
OnFailure=wd_keepalive.service

[Service]
Type=forking
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/watchdog
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -z "${watchdog_module}" ] || [ "${watchdog_module}" = "none" ] || /sbin/modprobe $watchdog_module
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_watchdog != 1 ] || exec /usr/sbin/watchdog $watchdog_options'
ExecStopPost=/bin/sh -c '[ $run_wd_keepalive != 1 ] || false'

[Install]
```

**How can I debug this, and get watchdog to run on boot**

---

I added the following to `/lib/systemd/system/watchdog.service`

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

`watchdog` now starts. I will need to test to ensure that it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known Debian bug.  The systemd integration of the Debian watchdog package has gone through several rounds, varying quite wildly.  The watchdog package that went out as Debian 8 was actually non-functional, as you have discovered.  That wasn't picked up by pre-release testing.

The bug has been fixed for version 5.15-1 of the package, alongside another fix that corrects faulty service unit syntax (also visible in your service unit).  This version is not available in Debian 8 backports, although two requests have been made (and apparently ignored) for it to be.

## Further reading

- Paul Menzel (2016-09-19). *[Syntax error in systemd service file](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=838305)*.  Bug #838305.  Debian bug tracker.
- Uwe Storbeck (2014-11-05). *[watchdog does not start at boot](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=768168)*.  Bug #768168.  Debian bug tracker.
- Andreas Steinel (2015-07-22). *[Not starting automatically on freshly installed Jessie](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=793309)*.  Bug #793309.  Debian bug tracker.
- Michael Meskes (2016-02-26).  *[Accepted watchdog 5.15-1 (source amd64) into unstable](https://packages.qa.debian.org/w/watchdog/news/20160226T123638Z.html)*.  debian-devel-changes.

Comment: Could you please tell what should do I, the ordinary user of OSMC on Raspberry Pi 3, to make watchdog work and start automatically? Writing/not writing to /dev/watchdog works. Fine that you provided some links where are some informations, but I do not know what to do with them.

Answer (score 1):

For armbian, you can install updated package manually:

```
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/watchdog/watchdog_5.15-2_armhf.deb
dpkg -i watchdog_5.15-2_armhf.deb
systemctl enable watchdog
```